# What is may-september-situation?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

In *The Blacklist*, episode S03E05, about 27:30 in, a guy asks something like this.

> Some say it's a daddy-daughter thing.
>   Others swear it's a may-september...

What does it mean? I haven't heard that reference before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A May-September romance is a relationship in which one partner is significantly older than the other.  May is in the spring and represents vitality and youth, perhaps a 20-30 year old person.  September is the beginning of autumn and represents a person entering their later years, perhaps 40-60.

You can also use May-December, particularly for relationships with extreme age differences, perhaps a 20 year old marrying an 80 year old.

There is no implied gender relationship between the ages; it is used both for young woman + old man and young man + old woman.

Comment: I recon that the oldie gets to be set at different months, slightly correlated to the actual age. Is may always fixed? Would *April-November* be a proper expression? Would *January-June* imply pedophilia?

Comment: @KonradViltersten May-September and May-December are the only two I've ever heard, though if you modified it in context it would probably be understood.  I can certainly imagine a conversation like the following: Person A: "Jane just married Mark, can you believe it?  He's 18 and she's turning 65 this year!"  Person B: "I guess some people are into that May-September thing."  Person A: "May-September?  More like February-November..."  If you led with Feb-Nov, it would just be confusing, but as a followup comment it makes sense.

Comment: As far as January-June goes, yes, I guess it would, but again, it's not really used that way, so it would only work after someone had mentioned May-September or May-December.

Comment: The oldest form of this metaphor used January (as a type of winter) for the old partner and May (as a type of spring) for the young one -- see Chaucer's *Merchant's Tale* where the old husband and young bride are actually named January and May. But in Chaucer's day the year began in March.